# data bind weather id value to i class in mvc razor view using KO

Tags: css, json, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Just  trying to implement a weather forecast in my MVC5 App View using KO.
To be able to display the weather icon  I have to fetch the  id from the observable weather array,  which I am able to obtain as follows:

```
<span data-bind="text:weather()[0].id"></span>
```

Then I have to put the id value of a particular city eg "801" in the i class like below:

```
<i class="wi wi-owm-ID value here+ "></i>
```

to display as

```
<i class="wi wi-owm-801"></i>
```

I am using the weather class

```
public Object getWeatherForcast()
        {
            string appid = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Auckland&APPID=" + appid + "&units=metric";

            var client = new WebClient();
            var content = client.DownloadString(url);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content);
            return jsonContent;
        }
```

Everything works I am just struggling to display the weather Id in the   so that an icon could be picked from the css file.  Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `class` observable with Knockout, like this:

```
<i data-bind="attr: {class: 'wi wi-owm-'+weather()[0].id()}"></i>
```

or

```
 <i data-bind="css: 'wi wi-owm-'+weather()[0].id()"></i>
```

Check fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/fhxg4e72/)

Comment: Thanks I tried to implement but I am geting this output   I dont know what is gone missing <i data-bind="attr: {class: 'wi wi-owm-'+weather()[0].id}" class="wi wi-owm-function d(){if(0<
arguments.length)return d.Pa(c,arguments[0])&amp;&amp;(d.X(),c=arguments[0],d.W()),this;a.k.Jb(d);return c}"></i>

Comment: I just did some research and found out that making it like this <i data-bind="attr: {class: 'wi wi-owm-'+weather()[0].id()}"></i> works.  If you can edit your answer I will accept it.  Also <i data-bind="css: 'wi wi-owm-'+weather()[0].id()"></i> works

Comment: I updated the answer. It worked with `id()` instead of `id` probably because you have the `id` property as observable. The `css` option I thought required slightly different syntax but glad it worked too - I added it to the answer for the benefit of future users.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate css class in the model and pass it to the markup via "css" binding:

```js
function model() {
  var result = {
    id: 15,
    style: undefined
  };
  result.style = ko.computed(function() {
      return "some-prefix-" + result.id;
    });
  return result;
};

ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

```css
.some-prefix-15 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="css: style"></div>
```

Comment: Could you guide me with implementation in context with my problem